# Pass messages between pool processes in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am new to python multiprocessing. I am writing a redis pubsub module in which a publisher reads data from a database table and publishes the data on a channel. At subscribers side I intend to create a number of worker processes which can listen to the channel by subscribing to it, get the item from channel and perform some operation on it. I want to stop all pool processes when any process gets a `END` string from channel. For this I am using `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` to communicate among pool processes. My subscriber module is below:

```
import redis
import time
import traceback
import json
import multiprocessing as mp
import contextlib

NO_OF_PROCESS = 4

def newProcess(queue):
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    p = r.pubsub()
    p.subscribe('subChannel')

    while True:
        print ('Waiting...')
        if (queue.get() == 'END'):
            break 
        # Do some work from message
        message = p.get_message()
        print (message)
        if message:
            data = message['data']
            # If 'END' received than stop all pool processes by setting a message in shared queue
            if data == b'END':
                queue.put('END')
                break
            else:
                data = json.loads(data)
                print (data)
       time.sleep(1)


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, NO_OF_PROCESS):
        self.NO_OF_PROCESS = NO_OF_PROCESS
        self.queue = mp.Manager().Queue()
        self.pool = mp.Pool(processes = NO_OF_PROCESS)

    def doWork(self):
        [self.pool.apply(newProcess, args=(self.queue)) for i in range(self.NO_OF_PROCESS)]



def parallelExec():
    worker = Worker(NO_OF_PROCESS)
    worker.doWork()

parallelExec()
```

The problem here is I am getting following error when I try to execute:
`TypeError: newProcess() argument after * must be an iterable, not AutoProxy[Queue]`. Please help, also if there is any other approach than I would like to hear.

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending args as iterable, converting args to a tuple by adding a comma should resolve the issue

```
        [self.pool.apply(newProcess, args=(self.queue,)) for i in range(self.NO_OF_PROCESS)]
```